# What VPN protocol(s) work standard with macOS, iPhone and Windows

Tags: vpn

macOS and Windows both have built-in VPN clients but they use different protocols.

What is the intersection of the protocols which are supported by macOS, Windows and iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

[Modern versions of macOS support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206844):

- L2TP/IPSec
- IKEv2/IPSec
- Cisco IPSec

TODO: Review iPhone

Ac

[Windows 10 supports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/access-protection/vpn/vpn-connection-type):

- IKEv2
- L2TP
- PPTP
- SSTP (does not work on mobile)